# GitHub SCIM Cross Identity Identifier ISSUE

Tags: github, github-api, saml, scim

I am using GitHub Enterprise Cloud, and in one of the organization I have enabled the SAML SSO and therefor I am able to use SCIM endpoints to create , update and delete USERS. After I create the user, GitHub sends them an invite to join the organization but I also want to give them access once they have joined the organization, for which I require the username but the user I am not able to find the username linked to the SCIM user or identity or email. How can I map username and emailID for this organization users provisioned by SCIM

userName in the scim endpoints as payload don't seem to have much role